FreeRadius with Step-CA
I have a Freeradius server setup with EAP-TLS on Ubuntu currently utilizing the OpenSSL to generate client certificates and CRL updates. I want to make this setup more convenient and easy to deploy. I'm looking at Step-CA which has ACME and API support which will absolutely make a huge difference when handling certificate creation and renewal. I can script workstations into renewing their own certs and new deployment can be done if a machine is connected to a guest network avoiding having to be onsite.
I haven't been able to find any guides or tutorials on how to integrate Freeradius with Step-CA. I'm hoping someone here will be able to put me into a right direction.
Thank you!
